# Convert List<objects> to a Dict <String, String> in C#

Tags: c#, json, dictionary

I want to create an app that shows me the value of a certain coin. I use KuCoin API. When I request pricing info, i get this response:

```
{
    "code": "200000",
    "data_fiat": {
        "LOKI": "0.39646657",
        "EXY": "0.01427250",
        "IOTX": "0.00411990",
        "MHC": "0.0035",
        "MXW": "0.14063173",
        ...
    }
}
```

I used Deserialze, and a Foreach loop to convert this to a List of data_fiat objects. 
Now, when I want to get a value I just type data_fiat.LOKI.

The problem is that I would need to create an IF for every possible coin (200+) and its ugly code. Is there a way to somehow convert this to a DICTIONARY, so I can use data_fiatDict[VAR]?

This is what I have now:

```
public static async Task<List<data_fiat>> GetPrices()
{
    FiatPrices data = new FiatPrices();
    List<data_fiat> price = new List<data_fiat>();

    string url = $"https://api.kucoin.com/api/v1/prices";
    using (HttpClient client = GetHttpClient())
    {
        try
        {
            string json = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
            data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FiatPrices>(json);
            foreach (data_fiat item in data.price)
            {
                price.Add(item);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
    return price;
}
```

This returns a LIST of data_fiat

```
private async Task GenerateData(Coins Selection)
{
    Coindata.BindingContext = Selection;
    String CoinSelection = Selection.Name;
    pricelbl.Text = ??Dictionary??[CoinSelection];
}
```

So I need a dictionary or something like that to be in the ??Dictionary?? spot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you declare the `FiatPrices` class with a dictionary, JsonConvert will automatically deserialize into this dictionary.

```
public class FiatPrices
{
    [JsonProperty("code")]
    public int Code { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("data_fiat")]
    public Dictionary<string, decimal> Prices { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can deserialize and query with

```
FiatPrices data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FiatPrices>(json);
decimal price = data.Prices["IOTX"];
```

If you only need the dictionary, you can extract it with a single assigment (no need to loop):

```
Dictionary<string, decimal> priceDict = data.Prices;
```

or in your `GetPrices` method with an adapted return type of `Task<Dictionary<string, decimal>>`:

```
return data.Prices;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `JObject` and select the node you need, then deserialize it to `Dictionary<string,string>`.

so instead of doing this :

```
data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FiatPrices>(json);
foreach (data_fiat item in data.price)
{
    price.Add(item);
}
```

you could do this :

```
JObject jObj = JObject.Parse(json);

var data_dictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(jObj["data_fiat"].ToString());
```

Comment: For some reason this code gets to an infinite loop (checked it using a break point), when trying to fill up de dictionary. Though Olivier has already found a working solution

Comment: @TiboVanZwol that's weird, I've tested in sync operation, and it works just fine. Even on asyc operation, it should work probably. At least, you've got more options to solve your question. ;).

Comment: Changing the FiatPrices class probably is the reason why your solution didnt work, it should indeed work as far as I know.